# Generic type function: Property does not exist

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a generic function `logVisitorInfo<T>`, with two fields. One is named `type`, defined as (`"registeredUser"` or `"anonymous"`). The second is named `info`, contains the information of the visitor (`ip`, `username`).

The generic function `logVisitorInfo` will type `info` to change based on the value of `type`.

But I am having a problem inside `logVisitorInfo` function:

```
type visitorType = {
    registeredUser: {
        ip: string;
        username: string;
    };
    anonymous: {
        ip: string;
    }
}
const logVisitorInfo = <T extends keyof visitorType>({ type, info }: {type: T, info: visitorType[T] }) => {
    const username = info.username; //error as expected, 'username' not exist on '{ ip: string; }'
   
    if(type === 'registeredUser') { //type is narrowed down to 'registeredUser', username should exists by now?
        const username = info.username; //but here still getting the same error
    }
}
```

It seems that `type === 'registeredUser'` doesn't do what I'm expecting. How can I avoid that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript won't narrow `info` based on the type of `type`, which makes sense if you consider this application:

```
logVisitorInfo<'registeredUser' | 'anonymous'>({type: 'registeredUser', info: {ip: ''}})
```

Both `type` and `info` are correctly typed here, but `info` doesn't contain `username`.

To get the behavior you want, you can create a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) type like this:

```
type Info = {[K in keyof VisitorType]: {type: K, info: VisitorType[K]}}[keyof VisitorType]
// type Info =
//  | { type: 'registeredUser'; info: { ip: string; username: string } }
//  | { type: 'anonymous'; info: { ip: string } }
```

Using `Info`, you can write `logVisitorInfo` without generics:

```
const logVisitorInfo = ({ type, info }:Info) => {
    const username = info.username; //error as expected, 'username' not exist on '{ ip: string; }'

    if(type === 'registeredUser') {
        const username = info.username;
    }
}

logVisitorInfo({type: 'anonymous', info: {ip: ''}}) // Ok
logVisitorInfo({type: 'registeredUser', info: {ip: ''}}) // Error
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQ35Vm)

Comment: Yes. That is what I want. Thanh you very much for the time and help